# Looping over timestamp and create dataframes by applying a set of filters in pandas

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to loop over timestamp and apply filters and create individual dataframes based on these filters. I have a dataset in which I have to loop over each hour of all 31 days in a month and create a dataframe for each hour of 31 days. Here is my Code please provide me suggestions

```
`df1 = df[df['Station'] == 'ANANDVIHAR']
for row in df1.iterrows():
y = y.hour
    df2 = df1[(df1['FromTime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour) == 00) & (df1['Month'] == 'Dec')]`
```

Here is my dataset

```
        Id     Station Month Concentration            FromTime
0        1  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        285.17 2015-12-01 00:00:00
1        2  ANANDVIHAR   Dec         260.5 2015-12-01 01:00:00
2        3  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        232.27 2015-12-01 02:00:00
3        4  ANANDVIHAR   Dec           225 2015-12-01 03:00:00
4        5  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        225.55 2015-12-01 04:00:00
5        6  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        232.82 2015-12-01 05:00:00
6        7  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        255.83 2015-12-01 06:00:00
7        8  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        292.67 2015-12-01 07:00:00
8        9  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        360.64 2015-12-01 08:00:00
9       10  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        386.33 2015-12-01 09:00:00
10      11  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        277.17 2015-12-01 10:00:00
11      12  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        243.83 2015-12-01 11:00:00
12      13  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        225.91 2015-12-01 12:00:00
13      14  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        234.73 2015-12-01 13:00:00
14      15  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        192.09 2015-12-01 14:00:00
15      16  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        192.64 2015-12-01 15:00:00
16      17  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        187.27 2015-12-01 16:00:00
17      18  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        179.67 2015-12-01 17:00:00
18      19  ANANDVIHAR   Dec           233 2015-12-01 18:00:00
19      20  ANANDVIHAR   Dec         268.8 2015-12-01 19:00:00
20      21  ANANDVIHAR   Dec           309 2015-12-01 20:00:00
21      22  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        296.67 2015-12-01 21:00:00
22      23  ANANDVIHAR   Dec           310 2015-12-01 22:00:00
23      24  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        314.73 2015-12-01 23:00:00
24      25  ANANDVIHAR   Dec         334.5 2015-12-02 00:00:00
25      26  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        312.67 2015-12-02 01:00:00
26      27  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        234.33 2015-12-02 02:00:00
27      28  ANANDVIHAR   Dec           200 2015-12-02 03:00:00
28      29  ANANDVIHAR   Dec        207.83 2015-12-02 04:00:00
29      30  ANANDVIHAR   Dec         264.5 2015-12-02 05:00:00
...    ...         ...   ...           ...                 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So ... something like this?

```
dfs = []
for hour in range(24):
    dfs.append(df1[(df1['FromTime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour) == hour) & (df1['Month'] == 'Dec')])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much